# Apex trigger is showing 0% coverage, apex test is failing to update because contact name field is blank?

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I wrote and confirmed working an ApexTrigger in a sandbox that looks like this:

```
trigger LastTouched on FeedComment(after insert, after update){

List<Case> updates = new List<case>();
Set<Id>feedItemIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Id> feedItemList = new List<id>();

Map<id,user> userMap = new Map<Id,User>([SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Support_Team_Member__c = true]); 

for(FeedComment fc: trigger.new){
    if(userMap.containsKey(fc.InsertedById)){ // only add them to the list if they are the right user
        feedItemIds.add(fc.FeedItemId);
    }
}

if(!feedItemIds.isEmpty()){
    for(Case c : [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id IN (SELECT ParentId FROM FeedItem WHERE Id IN :feedItemIds)]){
        updates.add(new Case(id = c.Id, Last_Updated_By_Support__c = System.now()));
    }
}

update updates;
}
```

The code for this test is kinda hacky.

```
@isTest
private class TestTouched {
    @isTest static void testLastUpdated(){
        //Create a new test case
        Account a = new Account(name='test acc',phone='7777777777');
        insert a;
        Contact con = new Contact(accountid=a.id,email='test@test.com');
        con.FirstName = 'Testy';
        con.LastName = 'mcTest';
        insert con;
        Case testCase = new Case(Status = 'New', Priority = 'Medium', Description = 'Test', Last_Updated_By_Support__c = System.now(), Contact = con );
        insert testCase ;
        //Create a new feed item (Post) on the test case
        Feeditem fi = new feeditem();
        fi.Body = 'test Post on case';
        fi.Type = 'TextPost';
        //Create a new comment on the post in the case
        fi.ParentId = testCase.Id;
        insert fi ;
        FeedComment fc = new FeedComment(CommentBody = 'test', FeedItemID = fi.Id);
        fc.CommentType = 'TextComment';
        insert fc ;
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Contact Name Field is Required.: []
```

Stack Trace: Class.TestTouched.testLastUpdated: line 10, column 1

Why is this running in my sandbox and not in Prod?  What do I need to do to fix this?

Note trying to set con.name = 'test'; tells me the field cannot be written...

Comment: N.B. you should mock a user in the testmethod that has `Support_team_member = true` as otherwise your tests rely on org data that could vary between test/prod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your org will have validation rules on Contact. You'll want to see what those validation rules are. Most all orgs will want to see at a minimum and email address (your case will typically require one) and also a phone number or address for the contact, depending on the validation rules your org has configured. It appears your sandbox must not have been configured to include all the validation rules your org uses. There may be rules in your org for example that prevent names like "test" or names with numbers (I've seen this).

By default, Salesforce expects every contact to have an email address. It's used as an externalId.

Comment: I'm an engineer with very little exposure to how Salesforce sets up these validation rules -- I disabled a lot of the required fields on the case object to ensure that my test would pass, but I can't find a similar way to disable validation rules on the contact object.  I just need the test to pass once as the Apex trigger has a VERY narrow scope and can only update a single field...

Comment: N.B. Only `Contact.Lastname` is required, `Contact.Email` is optional in the schema (albeit highly useful)

Comment: It may have changed. Years ago contact.email was a required field. You know how it is with SF Development, blink and the rules change. :P

Answer (score 0):

The above answer (which I marked as correct) is correct.  In my case there was a validation rule on the Case object forcing the name to be in a List of names which were tied to accounts and some other nonsense.  Salesforce documentation does an AWFUL JOB of explaining this functionality to the developer.   It's worth noting that you can disable this sort of validation to deploy your apex trigger / test -- so long as your trigger isn't going to violate the validation rule when it runs.